# Confused about When to use JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, jsonp

```
 $.ajax({ 
 headers:{
 "X-Mashape-Key": "P635I6rEYTmsh4jWyNQz8DB7xdR9p1kDVsejsnsJDPj4jTIfMy",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Accept": "application/json"
},
url:'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/',
type:"POST",
success:function(data){...}
})
```

In one of my project,my request code is posted above.In this project,l use an webapi,so l wanna ask why it worked without JSONP and doesn't it contain the problem of cross-domain?

So I am a little confused about when to use JSONP?Can anyone help me and hhank you guys in advance!

Comment: Try going through - [What JSONP is all about ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about?rq=1), it has nice explanation.

Comment: Hint: JSONP only work for GET request. You are using `POST`.

Comment: @lin  
Yeah,l know,but if l change post to get,it still work

Comment: @Teqchiqe thank you,i will go through it

Comment: @Teqchiqe l have read about it,but still the same question.Why my code above doesn't use JSONP to make request and worked